# Canceling active state of button

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I'm, using an `css` to control animation when pressing button with this code:

```
.btn_1:active {
 background-color: #4E4F4F;
}
```

but when displaying the page in mobile phone I touch the `button` and dragging my finger over the button without releasing it over the button, the button stays in `active` state.

How can I cancel it when passing over the button?

Comment: Not with CSS, no; and why would you want to? If your finger is down while it's over the button then the button *is* active (since lifting your finger would trigger the button's click event). The reason this differs from mouse-events is because holding the left mouse-button down, and then dragging, selects text/content (this isn't equivalent for the touch-drag gesture).

Comment: That's the problem,when i lifting my finger not over he button, after I drugged it, the button stays active until another touch.

Comment: @DavidThomas Correct would be that `click` events can be cancelled by dragging. A selection is only started when the pointer is not over a button. The same is true for touch devices where dragging the finger from a button usually prevents the `touchend` event being fired on it. However this normally should also cancel the `active` state since we use this successfully in multiple places. @alexOpent, please post your html and JavaScript involved so we can investigate further. Are we really talking about a button or an anchor acting as such?

Comment: Since there is no full example, I'm not sure if this works in your case, but using :focus instead of :active has helped me in the past for some touch-issues.
http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/RxvN5/